# Include SVG into three.js module to avoid separate HTTP request

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js

I'm working on a small site that has a very simple 3d animation in it. The model is extruded from an SVG file that is loaded using SVGLoader. I'd like to optimize loading speed and include the SVG as text into my threejs code so it doesn't need to do separate http request but has it already loaded and so it can be executed instantly.

How would you go about this? Would it be easier if it was an STL?

I just want to get rid of that separate http request basically and include the model with the code.

Code for my approach so far using the loader: https://github.com/riccardolardi/studioriccardolardi/blob/master/src/components/BG.svelte#L45

Thanks!

Comment: convert the SVG to a data URL I guess.

Comment: @RobertLongson but how to bypass the SVGLoader? If I have the SVG as data uri I cannot use the same mechanics as I would (for extrusion, etc.) since the Loader returns a "data" object that is specific to threejs

Comment: I don't know, you haven't provided any code to show what you're doing.

Comment: @RobertLongson here is what I'm trying to do https://github.com/riccardolardi/studioriccardolardi/blob/master/src/components/BG.svelte#L45

Answer (score 2):

Using of `.parse()`:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { SVGLoader } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/SVGLoader.js';

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.set(0, 10, 10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper());

let svg = `<svg height="250" width="500">
  <polygon points="220,10 300,210 170,250 123,234" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />
</svg>`;

let dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
dirLight.position.setScalar(10);
scene.add(dirLight);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

let svgLoader = new SVGLoader();
let data = svgLoader.parse(svg);
data.paths.forEach(dp => {
  let shapes = dp.toShapes(true);
  shapes.forEach(sh => {
    let g = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(sh, {bevelEnabled: false, depth: 2});
    g.center();
    let m = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFACE8D});
    let o = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
    o.scale.setScalar(0.05);
    console.log(o);
    scene.add(o);
  });
  
});

renderer.setAnimationLoop(()=>{
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to transform the SVG to generate shape defintions by passing the SVG content as a string directly to `SVGLoader.parse()`. The [parse](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/ObjectLoader.parse) method is differnet on each Loader in Three.js and is therefore not documented in a generic way. Thanks to Mugen87 from discourse.threejs.org who pointed that out to me.